# Cut off a name, Magento 2 widget

Tags: php, magento2

I'm trying to cut off titles from 32 caracters in a Magento 2 widget.

I made the override, and that's working (tested), and now try to shorten the title. I found several topics, and tried hard, but can't make it work.

My work so far:

```
<strong class="product-item-name">
    <?php  
         $product-name : $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName());
         $truncated = (strlen($product-name) > 32) ? substr($string, 0, 32) . '...' : $product-name;
     ?>
     <a title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"
      href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>"
      class="product-item-link">
          <?php echo $truncated; ?>
      </a>
</strong>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a small mistake.

```
$truncated = (strlen($product-name) > 32) ? substr($string, 0, 32) . '...' : $product-name;
```

at here `substr($string, 0, 32)` you can see `$string` variable which is not defined.

So rather then you need to use `$product-name` instead of it.

also you have another several mistakes too.

like `$product-name : $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName());` there should be
`$product-name = $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName());`

Also you needs to change a variable like this `$product-name` to `$product_name`

Hope this will help you

```
<strong class="product-item-name">
    <?php  
         $product_name = $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName());
         $truncated = (strlen($product_name) > 32) ? substr($product_name, 0, 32) . '...' : $product_name ;
     ?>
     <a title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"
      href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>"
      class="product-item-link">
          <?php echo $truncated; ?>
      </a>
</strong>
```

Comment: Thanks. didn't find it yet. In the mean time I found out: declaring the $product-name in the first php line is false? I used both = and : but it gives a error in the serverlog.

Comment: What you didn't found out?

Comment: sorry.. wanted a new line, and pressed Enter.. But this: declaring the $product-name in the first php line is false? I used both = and : but it gives a error in the serverlog

Comment: So it was the wrong declaration of $product_name in stead of $product-name. What's the difference? (I'm learning :) )